# A mysterious conserved quantity for a central potential

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian, poisson-brackets, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

In teaching a course in classical mechanics and I have come across (from my predecessor) a to me mysterious conserved quantity.

We are considering a gravitational (or electric) potential with the Hamiltonian
$$ H = \frac{p_r^2}{2m} + \frac{p_\theta^2}{2mr^2} - \frac{k}{r}. $$

The quantity in question is 
$$ A_x = \frac{p_\theta^2\cos\theta}{r} - mk\cos\theta + p_rp_\theta\sin\theta$$

Using Poisson brackets you can show that $\{H,A_x\}=0$ so $A_x$ is conserved.

What puzzles me is that it has dimensions of J*m*kg so it's is not a strange linear combination of angular momenta. It also explicitly contains the potential strength $k$, which looks a bit odd.

My question is simply, what is the interpretation of $A_x$?

Comment: Looks like the $x$-component of the [Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Lenz_vector). The Runge-Lenz vector encodes the position of the perihelion.

Comment: [More on the Runge-Lenz vector](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runge-lenz-vector).